# What are these auto-generated files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, vspackage

I'm developing a VSPackage and I need to know the meaning of all the files in my project, and there are some that I don't recognize:

- Guids.cs
- Key.snk
- PkgCmdID.cs
- policies.pkgdef
- resoursed.resx
- Settings.cs
- source.extention.vsixmanifest
- vspackage.resx
- *MySulotion*.vcst

What are these files for?

Comment: Any one?? even part of the files will be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### source.extension.vsixmanifest

This is the so-called VSIX manifest file which plays vital role in the discovery and registration mechanism of Visual Studio extensions.

### FirstLook.vsct

The so-called command table file storing the definition of the menus and commands to be merged into the Visual Studio IDE during the registration process.

### FirstLookPackage.cs

Class implementing the simple functionality of the package.

### GlobalSupressions.cs

Attributes used to suppress messages coming from the static code analysis.

### Guids.cs

GUID values used to identify the package and command objects within the package.

### Key.snk

Signing key used to generate the strong name for the package assembly.

### PkgCmdID.cs

Constants for identifying command values.

### Resources.resx

Resource file to store your functional package resources — resources you use according to the functions you implement in the package.

### VSPackage.resx

Resource file to store package infrastructure resources — those resources which are used by Visual Studio to integrate your package into the IDE.

[Source](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2010/03/02/VisualStudioPackages.aspx)